# Cartesian Product Equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The cartesian product of A={1,2} and B={2,1} are equal ?  Literally, A X B = B X A ?

I know that order isn't important with sets but i still doubt they equal the same.

Comment: To emphasize, $\{1,2\}\times \{3,4\}$ is not equal to $\{3,4\}\times\{1,2\}$ so cartesian product is not commutative in general.  The only reason why here $A\times B$ was equal to $B\times A$ was specifically *because* $A$ happened to be equal to $B$.  In fact, you will find the only scenarios where $A\times B=B\times A$ are when $A=B$ or when $A$ or $B$ were equal to the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just because $A=B$, so both products are just $A\times A = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well $A=B$ so both sets are $A^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.